# How to temporarily disable mouse device?

Tags: devices, mouse

I have wireless USB keyboard and mouse combo.

I need a way to disable mouse while leaving keyboard function working and a way to enable it again after some time.

I don't use X and I can't make it in desktop space as I use plain EGL, so it has to be done *deeper*, I guess in kernel space.

I tried to play with `/sys/bus/usb/*` stuff and I managed only to disable whole USB device, but that wasn't what I need as both keyboard and mouse were disabled.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post the output of `lsusb -t`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe zap the driver:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse #run without the -r to reenable
```

Comment: This would work if I use psmouse module, but I don't :(

Comment: Then find what module you're using. `lsmod | grep -iP '(mouse|touch|pointer)'` or something like that.

Comment: I don't use it as module, it's build it kernel as HID USB driver. But that is good idea, I will investigate in that way.

Answer (score -1):

Does your mouse have an off switch on the bottom of it? I used to use a logitech m185 and both the keyboard and the mouse came as a combination with 1 usb. Both also had an on and off switch.